# SQL Server Pivot Trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Does anyone know how I can pivot this query so that the Manufacturer.name are the columns and the rows are the months, which are calculated in the sub-queries.

```
SELECT Manufacturer.manufacturer_id
      ,Manufacturer.name
      ,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(SalesOrderLineItem.price*SalesOrderLineItem.quantity), 0) 
        FROM SalesOrderLineItem 
        INNER JOIN Products 
            ON SalesOrderLineItem.product_id = Products.product_id 
        INNER JOIN SalesOrder 
            ON SalesOrderLineItem.order_id = SalesOrder.sales_order_id 
        INNER JOIN Client 
            ON SalesOrder.client_id = Client.client_id 
        WHERE products.manufacturer_id = Manufacturer.manufacturer_id 
          AND Client.client_id = '224' 
          AND SalesOrder.order_placed BETWEEN '2014-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-09-30 23:59:00') AS 'sep-14'
      ,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(SalesOrderLineItem.price*SalesOrderLineItem.quantity), 0) 
        FROM SalesOrderLineItem 
        INNER JOIN Products 
            ON SalesOrderLineItem.product_id = Products.product_id 
        INNER JOIN SalesOrder 
            ON SalesOrderLineItem.order_id = SalesOrder.sales_order_id 
        INNER JOIN Client 
            ON SalesOrder.client_id = Client.client_id 
        WHERE products.manufacturer_id = Manufacturer.manufacturer_id 
          AND Client.client_id = '224' 
          AND SalesOrder.order_placed BETWEEN '2014-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-10-31 23:59:00') AS 'oct-14'
      ,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(SalesOrderLineItem.price*SalesOrderLineItem.quantity), 0) 
        FROM SalesOrderLineItem 
        INNER JOIN Products 
            ON SalesOrderLineItem.product_id = Products.product_id 
        INNER JOIN SalesOrder 
            ON SalesOrderLineItem.order_id = SalesOrder.sales_order_id 
        INNER JOIN Client ON SalesOrder.client_id = Client.client_id 
        WHERE products.manufacturer_id = Manufacturer.manufacturer_id 
          AND Client.client_id = '224' 
          AND SalesOrder.order_placed BETWEEN '2014-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-11-30 23:59:00') AS 'nov-14'
      ,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(SalesOrderLineItem.price*SalesOrderLineItem.quantity), 0) 
        FROM SalesOrderLineItem 
        INNER JOIN Products 
            ON SalesOrderLineItem.product_id = Products.product_id 
        INNER JOIN SalesOrder 
            ON SalesOrderLineItem.order_id = SalesOrder.sales_order_id 
        INNER JOIN Client 
            ON SalesOrder.client_id = Client.client_id 
        WHERE products.manufacturer_id = Manufacturer.manufacturer_id 
          AND Client.client_id = '224' 
          AND SalesOrder.order_placed BETWEEN '2014-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-31 23:59:00') AS 'dec-14'
FROM Manufacturer
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try:

```
WITH DATA
AS
(
    SELECT Manufacturer.name AS ManufacturerName
          ,MONTH(SalesOrder.order_placed) AS MonthNumber
          ,ISNULL(SUM(SalesOrderLineItem.price*SalesOrderLineItem.quantity), 0) AS Total
    FROM SalesOrderLineItem 
    INNER JOIN Products 
        ON SalesOrderLineItem.product_id = Products.product_id 
    INNER JOIN SalesOrder 
        ON SalesOrderLineItem.order_id = SalesOrder.sales_order_id 
    INNER JOIN Client 
        ON SalesOrder.client_id = Client.client_id 
    INNER JOIN Manufacturer
        ON products.manufacturer_id = Manufacturer.manufacturer_id 
       AND Client.client_id = '224' 
       AND SalesOrder.order_placed BETWEEN '2014-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-31 23:59:00'
)
SELECT MonthNumber, [ManufacturerName1], [ManufacturerName2]
FROM DATA
PIVOT (MAX(Total) FOR ManufacturerName IN ([ManufacturerName1], [ManufacturerName2])) AS P;
```

Unfortunately, you have to hard code the Manufacturer names in the query or use dynamic SQL for unknown Manufacturers.

Comment: Hi, this is really goo! Only thing is the ISNULL for the quantity* price doesn't work - it still returns NULL. Its not the end of the world if it can't be achieved but it would be good.